# mvc routemap in areas ActionLink

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, html-helper

This is  doing my head in

On the routeConfig file I have the following

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

          routes.MapRoute(
          "Default",
          "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{title}",
          new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional, title = UrlParameter.Optional },
          new[] {"xxx.Controllers"}
           );

        }
```

And I am using Areas on of them called EN

and on ENAreaRegistration.cs I have

```
public override string AreaName
        {
            get
            {
                return "EN";
            }
        }


        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext  routes)
        {

           routes.MapRoute(
           "Menu",
           "EN/{action}/{id}/{title}",
           new { controller = "Category", action = "Index", id = 0, title = UrlParameter.Optional },
           new[] { "xxx.Areas.EN.Controllers" }
        );

           routes.MapRoute(
              "EN_default",
              "EN/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
              new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
              new[] { "xxx.Areas.EN.Controllers" }
              );


        }
    }
```

On the view I have

```
@Html.ActionLink( item.Title, item.Title,  "Category", new {id = item.id}, new {title = item.Title.Replace(" ", "-")} )
```

I am trying to get the following `http://localhost:59295/EN/catergory/1/My-Careers` – so that the id is used for the records.

But I am getting   `http://localhost:59295/EN/Category/My Career/1`
I want to use the id which is 1 to show the record, but all its taking is My Career
Please can someone help
Thanks
Hesh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand our question correct, should **ActionLink** be like this?

```
@Html.ActionLink( item.Title, item.Title, "Category", 
    routeValues: new {id = item.id, title = item.Title.Replace(" ", "-")},
    htmlAttributes: null)
```